# How do I use python-virtkey on centos6.5?

Tags: python

I have already installed python-virtkey on Centos6.5.But when I just want to create a new object of virtkey by using virtkey.virtkey(), an error occurred：failed initialize display. Is there anything else wrong?

Comment: You have a display server available?

Comment: Yes, I have.Here is my iso file: CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal

Comment: Can you copy the full error traceback and add it to your question?

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep  7 2015, 19:26:56) <br>
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import virtkey
>>> v = virtkey.virtkey()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
virtkey.error: failed initialize display :(
>>>

Comment: And you are on that machine with a graphical desktop?

Comment: Without graphical desktop.

Comment: Then we are back to comment #1: You have no display available. ("display" is an active X session). If you logging in via ssh, use `ssh -X …` if you are local, log in to a graphical session.

Comment: But my system does not support graphical session.

Comment: virtkey work on X servers. If you don't have any. Neither on that host nor on a client from where you can SSH into that machine with X redirection then you can not use virtkey.